# Get item from listview column convert to percent and display in the next column

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I want to get a number from a listview item divide it by the number in a text box and display it in the next column. How can i do this for every item in the listview? [image]

( i need to get amount / fraction denominator and output it into percentage )

Comment: I believe you're looking for the `OnDataBound` event of the listview.  There should be ample documentation online for this.

Comment: but how do you get the data from the listview item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

Added Two SubItems to ListView. One to display the actual value and other to display the result

```
foreach (ListViewItem lvi in listView1.Items)
            {
                lvi.SubItems.Add(YourValue.ToString());
                lvi.SubItems.Add("");
            }
```

and then in button click

```
foreach (ListViewItem lvi in listView1.Items)
            {
                double ItemText = Convert.ToDouble(lvi.SubItems[1].Text) / Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);
                lvi.SubItems[2].Text = ItemText.ToString();
            }
```

Comment: Ahh sorry i forgot to mention they were subitems, this is were i keep running into problems. I updated the question. any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
ListViewItem item = listView1.Items[ listView1.SelectedIndex ];
```

item.SubItems[ 1 ] = int.Parse( item.SubItems[0].Text ) / (float)denominator;

Haven't tried if it compiles, but that's the idea, right?